# [SerialDevice rs232- windows 10]not get value pin CTS in rs232

Tags: c#, serial-port, windows-10-universal

I'm using "SerialDevice" to send data from windows 10 pc to windows 10 tablet through RS232. 
i can not used function ClearToSendState() into SerialDevice to get value of pin CTS on the windows 10. i used soft terminal by bray to turn on pin RTS to 1. handshake RTS and CTS but into windows 10 not get value pin CTS.

Answer (score 1):

i used function CTSHolding() into SerialPort to get value pin CTS. that's ok.
but i'm coding universal on the windows 10. Can't use SerialPort.
I used function ClearToSendState() into SerialDevice to get value pin CTS but that's not work. it always false.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need that? If you just need serial communication, you usually don't need to manually change those pins. Just set the protocol to hardware and the port driver will do everything for you and automatically perform the float control. Alternatively, you should also be able to disable flow control altogether, because about any recent hardware (recent meaning less than 15 years old) is able to handle the 115kbaud transmission even without flow control flawlessly.

Comment: my project request 2 type communication:
- slip: not handshake rts/cts. like you cmt.
- rts/cts : handshake rts/cts. i code by SerialPort on the windows 7.it is good but  i code universal by SerialDevice on windows 10. it is errror (not get value CTS by function Cleartosend() into SerialDevice)

Comment: Show a piece of code, please. You might have a problem in your serial port implementation (neither of the methods you mention exist on the SerialPort class)

Comment: i used function CTSHolding() into SerialPort to get value pin CTS. that's ok. but i'm coding universal on the windows 10. Can't use SerialPort. I used function ClearToSendState() into SerialDevice to get value pin CTS but that's work. it always false.

Comment: code SerialPort act ok:  
public bool GetComCTSPin()
        {
            return m_SerialPort.CtsHolding;
        } 
code SerialDevice not work:
 public bool GetComCTSPin()
        {
            return m_SerialPort.ClearToSendState;
        }

Comment: That looks like a problem with the implementation of SerialDevice. I don't know that interface, so I can't help you there.